Android Studio Debug - cannot expand variables
About Box
I have upgraded to Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1 from the 2021 version. This was a fresh download and install from a .dmg file.
While debugging my Flutter application if execution stops at a breakpoint I can no longer see the current values in the Variables tab. For example: expanding the 'this' variable does not show the values of the field in the current  WorkingPart object.
variables tab
I have tried restarting Android Studio.  I have tried running flutter clean.
Possibly the JIT compiler is enabled and interfering with the evaluation of variables but I cannot find out if it is or how to turn it off.
